# ListBoxFor not letting me select multiple items MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

When I run the code, I can only select one item at a time, that's weird because 'ListBoxFor()' is used to select multiple items, so what i want is:

Select multiple items

View (Index.cshtml):

```
<div>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.DropDownItems, new MultiSelectList(Repository.DDFetchItems(), "Value", "Text", Model.DropDownItems))
</div>
```

Model (ModelVariables.cs):

```
public class ModelVariables
{
    public List<SelectListItem> DropDownItems { get; set; } 
}

public static class Repository
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> DDFetchItems()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){  Text = "Dogs", Value = "1", Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem(){  Text = "Cats", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem(){  Text = "Death", Value = "3"}
        };
    }
}
```

Controller (HomeController.cs):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ModelVariables model = new ModelVariables()
    {
        DropDownItems = Repository.DDFetchItems()  
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects (which is what `List<SelectListItem>` is). A `<select multiple>` posts back an array of simple values (in your case, if you select the 1st and 3rd options, it will submit `[1, 3]` (the values of the selected options).

Your model needs a `IEnumerable<int>` property to bind to.

```
public class ModelVariables
{
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownItems { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the GET method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ModelVariables= new ModelVariables()
    {
        DropDownItems = Repository.DDFetchItems(),
        SelectedItems = new List<int>(){ 1, 3 } // to preselect the 1st and 3rd options
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItems, Model.DropDownItems)
```

Side notes

1. Remove `Selected = true` in the `DDFetchItems()` method - its
   ignored by the `ListBoxFor()` method because its the value of the
   property your binding to which determines what is selected
2. There is not need to build a new identical `SelectList` from the
   first one inside the `ListBoxFor()` method (property `DropDownItems`
   is already `IEumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Comment: Very good, i got it to work, HOWEVER, i could not pre-select items because i cannot convert from 'int' to <SelectListItem>, SelectedItems =  new List<int>() { 1, 3 }, it wants <'SelectListItem'> instead of 'int', due to me changing public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }

Comment: You cant change it to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedItems` - that will never work as I explained (you **cannot** bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects and your app would fail if you did). It must be `IEnumerable<int> SelectedItems`

Comment: Ok i reverted it, now i get an error on x.Selected in  var selectedMDDItems = model.SelectedItems.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Text).ToList(); 'int does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'int'

Comment: No. Your not understanding. The `<select multiple>` will post back an array of `int` - so if you select the 2nd and 3rd options, then in the ost method, `model.SelectedItems` will be `[ 2, 3 ]`. You don't need any `Linq` to get the selected values - you can just use `foreach(int selected in model.SelectedItems) { .... }`

Comment: Oh dear. Your need to repopulate the `SelectList` is you return the view. Read through [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) to understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114800/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fluffywuffy).