# how to store Multiple selction / Dropdownlist in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

i'm new in MVC and C# and for a project im trying to let the user to multiselect cities from a list and store it to the DB later. Ive read couple of a few posts regarding this but couldnt figure out how to fix mine. I can store all the other items of my form:

```
@using ( Html.BeginForm( "AddProjectInfo", "Insert", FormMethod.Post, new {
        enctype = "multipart/form-data"
        @id = "insertform", @class = "form-horizontal col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"
    } ) )
```

but for city it only stores the first selected item not all. can you please help me to fix this?

Here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left">City * </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            @Html.DropDownList(
             "City",
             new SelectListItem[] {
                    new SelectListItem {
                        Text = "Cambridge", Value = "Ca"
                    },
                   new SelectListItem {
                        Text = "Oxford", Value = "Ox"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem {
                        Text = "Sheffield", Value = "Sh"
                    }                
             },
         "--Select Cities--",
    new {
        @class = "form-control",
        required = true,
        multiple = "multiple"
    }
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert( FormCollection frm ) {
        Models.ProjectInfo p = new Models.ProjectInfo();
        String[] Cities= frm.GetValues( "City" );
        p.ContractId = frm[ "ContractId" ];
        p.Year = Convert.ToDecimal( frm[ "Year" ] );
        p.City = Cities.ToString();
        p.Location = frm[ "Location" ];
        // Insert into the Database
            AddProjectInfo( p );
            ViewBag.ResponseMessage = "Submitted !";

    }
```

I know how to do that using JavaScript but dont know how C# can handle that. 
Thanks you!

Comment: public ActionResult Insert( FormCollection frm )  this should be a real model with fields corresponding to the inputs in html

Comment: Do not use `DropDownList()` with `multiple` - use `ListBoxFor()` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)). And never use `FormCollection`. Create a view model and bind to a property - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848223/listboxfor-not-letting-me-select-multiple-items-mvc/37848327#37848327) for a typical implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will tell you upfront that I wrote these examples without testing it, but it's just to give you a general idea of how to proceed correctly with dropdown lists / list boxes. Also, in the end, I will leave the link to my GitHub where I have a simple project which I wrote some time ago specially for cases like this.

So, let's get started. For the sake of simplicity I would rather have the dropdown list being created in the Controller. For example:

Let's assume you have a Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public SelectList CitySelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the `CitySelectList`, which is `NotMapped` since we don't want it to be connected to the DB. The value of `CitySelectList` will be saved in the DB through `City`

And then you have an Action Method:

```
public ActionResult Insert()
{
    var person = new Person { CitySelectList = new SelectList(
    new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Cambridge", Value = "Ca" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Oxford", Value = "Ox" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Sheffield", Value = "Sh" }
        }, "Value", "Text") };

    return View(person);
}
```

Here you can see that I am creating an instance of `Person` and passing it to the View. This is the best way to load a View with predefined values. And the most important predefined value in this case is the dropdown list.

The View would look more or less like this:

```
@model Person

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
@* Important *@
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CitySelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" } })
@* /Important *@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

}
```

As you can see I am calling the dropdown list through an EditorFor passing 2 htmlAttributes. The most important is `multiple = "multiple"` since this is the one which will define the type of item list I am going to show in the page. How? Through an Editor Template built specially to handle it. If you are not familiar with its concept and usage you can check [this website](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) for start. The editor template can be seen below:

```
@model SelectList

@{
    var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
}

@if (!htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("multiple"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model.SelectListItems, htmlAttributes)
}
else
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValues, Model.SelectListItems, htmlAttributes)
}
```

One detail on this particular Editor Template: Have you noticed that I am creating the Dropdown List / List Box for the SelectedValue(s)? That is something which might cause a bit of headache when you get all the values but you can handle, in your POST method, in this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert(Person person)
{
    person.City = person.CitySelectList.SelectedValues;
    // Some code goes here
    return View();
}
```

That should be it. But, as I said before, I have a working code [here](https://github.com/davidsonsousa/DropDownList) so you can run and see how it works. And also some explanation of that code from GitHub [right here](http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/the-best-way-to-use-dropdownlistfor-with-aspnet-mvc) in case you need.

Comment: Creating a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the 1st one by using `new SelectList(..)` is pointless. This gives no client or server side validation, cannot be used for correct 2-way model binding when editing existing data, will not set the value of `City` (`SelectedValues` is `IEnumerable`), will lose all options when `return View();` is called etc. etc.

Comment: Yes, but as I said in the very first line, "(...) I wrote these examples without testing it, but it's just to give you a general idea (...)".

Comment: The general idea is to strongly bind to a model property (which in OP case will be say `IEnumerable<string> SelectedCities`, not to the `SelectedValues` property of `SelectList` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.location_code, Model.location_type)        
    [HttpPost]
        public string SaveResults(List<int> location_code)
        {

            if (location_code!= null)
            {
                return string.Join(",", location_code);
            }
            else
            {
                return "No values are selected";
            }
        }
```