# Multiple selection with listboxfor/listbox post only last selected item

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, multi-select, html.listboxfor

I'm trying to do a multiple selection with ListBoxFor of Razor, but the select does not allow me to select multiple items (I can do that only selecting my items with Ctr+click the second item). I've reduced my code to minimal like the exemple shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848327/3692982) (my code is above). Anyone can help me?? I'm desperate.

My Model

```
public IEnumerable<int> ParoleChiave { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaParoleChiave { get; set; }
```

My Controller

```
model.ListaParoleChiave = new List<SelectListItem>() {
    new SelectListItem(){  Text = "Pro", Value = "2"},
    new SelectListItem(){  Text = "Test", Value = "3"}
};
```

My View

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-xs-12">Parole chiave</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ParoleChiave, Model.ListaParoleChiave, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100%" })                        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It's not depending from my ListBoxFor element, it was caused by the js code that I wrote to post to the server action my formData with additional data.
Basically it was like:

```
data: function (d) {                                                 
        var fd = new FormData(myForm[0]);
        for (var pair of fd.entries()) {
           d[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }                                         
        return d;
    }
```

I realized that the multiple values where posting like two entries (key/value pairs) of the FormData but with the same key name, so my code was overwriting the first entry with the second. I replaced with the code above and now it works like a charm.

```
data: function (d) {                                           
        var fd = new FormData(myForm[0]);
        for (var pair of fd.entries()) { 
            var occurenceOfKey = Array.from(fd.keys()).reduce(function (n, val) {
                 return n + (val === pair[0]);
            }, 0);
            if (occurenceOfKey > 1)                                                        
                d[pair[0]] = fd.getAll(pair[0]);              
            else
                d[pair[0]] = pair[1]; 
        }                                                             
        return d;
   }
```